# The difference between __main__ and launch() methods

Tags: python

I'm still in the learning phase and I have this question.

So in order to execute a class, we use `if __name__ == '__main__':` and call the class as the following

```
class Example():
     def test(self):
        print "Hello There"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example()
```

However, I saw some classes that use `def launch():` instead of `if __name__ == '__main__':`, so the question here: Are they similar so I can both ways or `def launch():` has a special propose?

Thank you.

Comment: there is no such thing as launch in python, he must have been declaring a function name just like you declared `def test()`. Nothing else.

Comment: I'm assuming that in your tutorial they created a function called `launch` and called the class from inside the function body to execute it?

Comment: Or was `launch` just another function in the class?

Comment: Would you mind giving us an example of the `launch` method?

Comment: @Harrison Thank you. You said `they created a function called launch and called the class from inside the function body to execute it?` Can you provide an example so I can compare? Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python runs anything in the top level this is why we use classes and functions to separate jobs (among other reasons).

So for example here

Script `a.py`

```
def main():
    pass

main()
```

The interpreter will define a function called `main()` but when it reaches the `main()` call in the top level (aligned left most)
it will execute the main function.

Now in the case of your `launch()`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example()
```

vs

```
__name__ = __main__
```

This is used in the case where someone wants to import a program or class but doesn't want it to run when the interpreter runs into it.

Import a will call the `main()` at that point and time
however let's say `b.py` is structurally similar but instead of `main()` it has `__name__ = __main__`, `b.py` won't run unless directly called.

The reason I bring this is up is because as @harshil9968 pointed out, Python has no "launch" method. What likely was happening is they defined a `launch()` method instead of `main()`

Then put it under a class

```
class A():
    def launch(self):
       #actions

if __name__ == '__main__':
     A()
```

Call to `A()` calls the `launch()` method within the `A` class.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well explained :)

Comment: Calling `A` doesn't call `launch()`.  Why should it?